# Kibana search with multiline data does not return data after newline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I'm very new to ElasticSearch and Kibana.  I have set up a LogStash that publishes a field that contains new lines - it is a Java stacktrace using the multiline codec.

The field that I'm searching on looks like:

```
Exception message of some sort all on the very first line\ntld.domain.package.Exception: Something bad happened!\n\tat tld.domain.other.package.method\n
```

I would like to find information from past the first new line character but my google-fu has not been able to locate an answer.

Any thoughts?